# Is there any way of checking the history of builds ran by me on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build, history

Each time I log on Jenkins I find myself having to type on the search bar the exact name of the build I am looking for and it would be very helpful if there was a section showing the history of your recently ran builds, anyone knows if such thing exists?

Comment: Have you looked into the `view-job-filters` plugin, especially the `Filter by Relevance to Logged-in User` section? https://plugins.jenkins.io/view-job-filters/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permissions within my association to install plugins on Jenkins

Comment: Can you execute scripts on the script-console then? I know the way below, but that's insufficient indeed. If you have access to execute scripts (https://<yourjenkinsurl>/script), then you can list something there as output.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have access to the scripts interface either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> http://<my_jenkins>:8081/user/<user_name>/builds

It should plot the builds that you've manually built. Seems that it doesn't support multibranch pipeline jobs.

Comment: It indeed shows some builds ran by me, but only some that are common for the organization, which I ran awhile ago. I was more focused on getting the ones built on my own created branches.